# Another application of the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

Let $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ i.i.d random variables with values in $\mathbb R^2$. Let $Z_n= \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i, n\in\mathbb N$. I want to calculate the weak limit $\frac {Z_n}{\sqrt n}$ if $Y_1\sim U\{(-1,0),(1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)\}$.

I think $\operatorname{E}(Y_1)=0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y_1)=1$. Then I think I have to compute the covariance matrix, it is then given by 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\operatorname{Var}(Y_1) & \operatorname{E}(Y_1)\\
\operatorname{E}(Y_1) & \operatorname{Var}(Y_1)
\end{pmatrix} 
=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
=:
A$$
Therefore $\frac{Z_n}{\sqrt n}$ converges to $N(0,A)$ by central limit theorem.

Is this reasoning correct? Actually I was not sure about the calculation of $\operatorname{Var}(X_1)$, it was more  a guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean that $Y_{1}$ can only take those 4 points listed in the set $U$, the Expected Value is

$\begin{align} E[Y_{1}] = \frac{1}{4}*(-1,0) + \frac{1}{4}*(1,0) + \frac{1}{4}*(0,1) + \frac{1}{4}*(0,-1) = 0 \end{align}$

and because the expected value is $0$ the variance is the 2nd moment.

But let's be a little more precise with our definition of $Y_1$ so we can talk about the variance-covariance matrix. We have that $Y_1 = (y_1, y_2)$ where you can think of $y_1,y_2$ as bernoulli(1,-1) random variables. If we take the expected value of a random vector we get

$E[Y] = (E[y_1], E[y_2]) = (0,0)$

and $y_1$ takes values 1,-1,0,0 with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each. The variance matrix of the random vector $X = (X_1,...,X_n)$ is the $nxn$ matrix defined as

$[Var(X)]_{ij} = Cov(X_i, X_j)$

If we calculate $Cov(y_1, y_1)=Var(y_1) = \frac{1}{4}(-1)^2 + \frac{1}{4}(1)^2 + \frac{1}{2}(0) + \frac{1}{2}(0) = \frac{1}{2}$

And the same thing works for $Cov(y_2,y_2)$

Then if we calculate $Cov(y_1, y_2) = E[y_1y_2]-E[y_1]E[y_2] = E[y_1y_2]$ which is clearly $0$ because the coordinates always have one being $0$ and the other being $1$ or $-1$.

Then its easier to write the covariance matrix $A$ as \begin{pmatrix}
\operatorname{Var}(y_1) & \operatorname{Cov}(y_1, y_2)\\
\operatorname{Cov}(y_2, y_1) & \operatorname{Var}(y_2)
\end{pmatrix} 
=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}& 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}

Which is the matrix you need for $A$

So now use the fact that the $Y_i$'s are independent and take $Var(Z_n) = Var(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n Var(Y_i) = nA$

Then looking at the quantity $\frac {Z_n - 0}{\sqrt n}$ we can easily see that $E[\frac {Z_n}{\sqrt n}] = 0$ and that $Var(\frac {Z_n - 0}{\sqrt n}) = \frac{1}{n}Var(Z_n) = \frac{nA}{n} = A$ so then applying the central limit theorem gives you $\frac {Z_n}{\sqrt n}$ goes to a two dimensional normal $N_2(0,A)$ as $n$ goes to infinity. So yes your reasoning is correct!

Comment: $U_E$ denotes the uniform distribution on E. Why did you actually calculate $Var(Z_n)$? I do not understand why we need this last part of your answer for applying CLT. But anyway thank you for your help and extensive answer!

Comment: I just wanted to show all the details, if you have the distribution of $Z_n$ then you can easily apply the CLT in a rigorous way. But anyway, hope that answered your question! You’re welcome!

Comment: I think we made a mistake with the calculation of $Var(Y_1)$ Each component should be $\frac12$..

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? It’s just the second moment of $Y_1$ because the expected value is $0$ right?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but don´t we have to consider the variance componentwise? Then for the first component $ y_1 $, $Var(y_1)=\frac14 -1^2 + \frac14 1^2 +0+0= \frac12$

Comment: Yes you’re right! I updated the answer, thanks for pointing that out